# Ranking for unique users

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have three columns:

id, username, time

My data is:

```
+-------+------------------+-------------+
|   id  |     username     |    time     |
+-------+------------------+-------------+
|   1   |        A         |    1 min    |
|   2   |        A         |    2 min    |
|   3   |        B         |    3 min    |
|   4   |        B         |    4 min    |
+-------+------------------+-------------+
```

This query is working to get the ranking:

```
   SELECT time, 
    FIND_IN_SET(MIN(time), (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(time ORDER BY time ASC) 
    FROM table t1)) AS rank
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t2.username = 'B';
```

There is only one problem: It returns Rank 3de for the user B instead 2nd.

So I tried to use **GROUP BY t2.username** and also **Distinct t2.username** but did not work.

How can I get the rank of THE user B? It should be 2 (**Not 3**) because we have only 2 users.

Comment: `MIN()` doesn't work on strings, you need to cast it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner `min()` does work on strings, it works *like* if it is an order by ASC limit 1

Comment: What is the value of `$order_by`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Ok. Well, I saw it here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-min/ and I quote: *"The MIN function is very useful in some scenarios such as finding the smallest number..."* and don't mention strings and don't know why as opposed to the official reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min

Comment: Can you paste the entire desired result - and $user_id is meaningless in the context of this question. And you're not really storing 'min', are you???

Comment: @Jorge Campos: it is ASC

Comment: @Strawberry 
I changed $user_id to username (For my real query I can use username or user_id).
I am not storing MIN.

Comment: $user_name is equally meaningless. Get rid of all the PHP. It's irrelevant to this problem

Comment: @Strawberry
I did. Thanks. I left only (WHERE t2.username = 'B') because we need it to get the Rank of the user B.

Comment: See. That's much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id  INT NOT NULL
,username CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,time TIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'A','00:01:00'),
(2,'A','00:02:00'),
(3,'B','00:03:00'),
(4,'B','00:04:00');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | time     |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | A        | 00:01:00 |
|  2 | A        | 00:02:00 |
|  3 | B        | 00:03:00 |
|  4 | B        | 00:04:00 |
+----+----------+----------+

SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT username
            , time
            , @i:=@i+1 rank 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT username
                   , MIN(time) time 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY username
            ) x
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY time
     ) n 
 WHERE username = 'B';
+----------+----------+------+
| username | time     | rank |
+----------+----------+------+
| B        | 00:03:00 |    2 |
+----------+----------+------+
```

I think this would work too, but it's slightly hacky, so I'm not sure...

```
SELECT x.*
     , FIND_IN_SET(time,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT time ORDER BY time) FROM (SELECT MIN(time) time FROM my_table GROUP BY username) j )) rank
  FROM my_table x HAVING rank <> 0 AND username = 'B';
```